# Embedding a youtube video into android app using eclipse? 

Tags: android, eclipse, youtube

I'm trying to figure out how to embed youtube videos into android using eclipse.  I would prefer to use the chromeless player, but at this point it's not necessary.

Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to embed a Youtube video is to use an intent to fire the Youtube application, like this:

```
String video_path = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opZ69P-0Jbc";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(video_path);

// With this line the Youtube application, if installed, will launch immediately.
// Without it you will be prompted with a list of the application to choose.
uri = Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"  + uri.getQueryParameter("v"));

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: awesome, thanks.  I am a little confused though, will I still be able to have my own GUI stuff to the left or right of the video, or does that code take it into an entirely different page?

Comment: With this code no as it launches the Youtube application. If you want your own GUI take a look at this free Youtube activity: http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/

Comment: I am also looking for a way to **EMBED** a YouTube video. Does anyone know how to **EMBED** a YouTube video?

Answer (score 3):

YouTube API for Android is availible now. Following [this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/), you will find a sample how to use YouTube API under Android.

Using YouTubePlayerView you can play video from youtube in your activity. But it is not possible to change default controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play the video from inside the application to really embed it you can use WebView and load it with just iframe of that youtube video.

```
WebView webview;
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadData("<iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZ4sDn89P04\"></iframe>","text/html","utf-8");
```