# How to embed and play a YouTube video in android

Tags: android, youtube

Can we watch youtube video in android app? I mean if we have link to video on youtube, can we play it in VideoView or another widget?
Any ideas about it?

Comment: Have you tried a google search at least? Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/5798922/782719

Comment: I don't need to open video in another app. I want play it in my app.

Comment: It is very simple, Enable Youtube API in developer console, download youtube player jar file & include it. Refer this example http://www.feelzdroid.com/2017/01/embed-youtube-video-player-android-app-example.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Answer is Simple "YES".

Please look at to following link,

[How to play YouTube video in my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654878/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-application)

[Streaming Youtube Videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007695/streaming-youtube-videos)

Answer (score 5):

First you should try to download the Youtube player library for Android from the link below:

[Youtube Android Player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)

You should first install it like this: Project -> menu: File > Structure > Dependencies Tab > Add -> library dependency

if it doesn't work, please try one of these two:

Add dependency of the library inside dependency inside build.gradle file of the library u r using, and paste ur library in External Libraries.

OR

Just Go to your libs folder inside app folder and paste all your .jar e.g Library files there Now the trick here is that now go inside settings.gradle file now add this line include ':app:libs' after include ':app' It will definitely work.

Then, you should have a layout like this:

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And you can have a player activity like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import java.io.IOException;

public class YoutubeActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity{

    private YouTubePlayerView playerView;
    private YouTube youtube;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);

        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest hr) throws IOException {}
        }).setApplicationName(this.getString(R.string.app_name)).build();


        playerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        playerView.initialize("Your API Key", new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                if(!b){
                    String videoId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoID");
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is an official YouTube Android Player API wich you can use. This is a bit more complicated but it is working better than other solutions using webclients.

First you must register your app in Googles API Console. This is completely free until your app gets over 25k request a month (or something like that). There are complete anf great tutorials under the link. I hope you can understand them. If not, ask! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can Use webview to do so. Here is the screen shot of of what it look like with webview :-

[image: YouTube with webview]

if this is what you want to achieve you can get sample app from  here :- https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Universal-Web-Content-Loader

It support both portrait & landscape mode.